# How do I import newly written function into a notebook in pychaarm?

Tags: pycharm

I'm using pycharm to edit a notebook (because I'm a non-python programmer and I know intellij)
I have a subfolder marked as source (blue in the project directory). In that file I have written a function that I'm trying to use.
But it tells me it can't import the function.

It can import a function that was already in the file.
So somehow it doesn't seem to recognise the new function or the source code update, even though the folder is marked as source.
I'm use to intellij - where you change one thing and the other things know about it.
Is this some virtualenv thing?

So 
mydir/notebooks/myproj.ipynb

mydir/notebooks/mypackage/myutils.py

where myutils contains the new function it cannot find

Comment: i should probably add, this is pycharm 2020.1 pro newly downloaded

Comment: This is not a useful answer but, closing down pycharm and the notebook and restarting it again gets over the problem.

OS is ubuntu 20.04